# Highlight comments background in jedit

Tags: jedit

Just started to use jEdit (I'm a die-hard vi/vim user) and I've come across a question already that I cannot find anywhere.

I want to display any comments in my source code not just in a different colour (I already have that) but also with a highlighted background colour. Unfortunately the shop I am working at currently has a policy of never deleting code but instead commenting out and adding to. Works fine with a few lines of code but occasionally I come across programs where hundreds of lines have been commented out and if it's first thing in the AM I sometimes find myself altering code that has already been commented out.

I know there is the ability to "fold" comments but I'm looking for a colour background alternative.

TIA

N/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies - the answer is in the options.

1. Highlight the token you are interested in.
2. Menu>Utilities>Quick Settings>Edit Syntax Style of Token Under Caret>Background Colour

N/